# How do I diff incoming changesets with Beyond Compare 4 and hg?

Tags: mercurial, beyondcompare

I have been using the mercurial and Beyond Compare 4 tools together for about 2 weeks now and feel fairly confident in my usage, however I still seem to have a problem when comparing incoming changesets against my current local codebase. The problem is emphasized when I attempting a complicated merge.

> **Just to clarify**, I am avoiding the use of tools such as TortoiseHg,
>   although I do have it installed. I am searching for feedback via cmd
>   line operations only.

My current templated method to pull down the incoming changesets via the following ( as an [alias] )

```
hg in --verbose -T "\nchangeset: \t{rev}\nbranch: \t{branch}\nuser: \t\t{author}\ndate: \t\t{date(date,'%m-%d-%Y %I:%M%p')}\ndescription: \n\t{desc|fill76|tabindent}\n\n{files % ' \t{file}\n'}\n----------\n"
```

As an example, here is a simplified (and cleverly abstracted) block returned ::

```
changeset:      4685
branch:         Feature-WI209825
user:           Jack Handy <jhandy@anon.com>
date:           01-19-2015 10:19AM
description:
        Display monkey swinging from vines while whistling dixie

        Zoo/MonkeyCage/Resources/Localization.Designer.cs
        Zoo/MonkeyCage/Resources/Localization.resx
        Zoo/MonkeyCage/Utility/Extensions.cs
```

If I were to be comparing changes locally, I would simply use the following command ::

```
hg bcomp -r 4685 -r default <optional file name>
```

and then I would get an instance of Beyond Compare with a folder structure and files and I could just navigate accordingly to view the changes...however, when I attempt to do this with a changeset that has yet to be pulled into my local repository, I can't.

How do I diff incoming changesets with my local repository?

**---- UPDATE --------------------------------**

I pursued the idea of bundling the incoming changes and then trying to use BC4 to diff the bundle to any given branch/revision on my local repo.

```
hg in --bundle "C:\Sandboxes\Temp\temp.hg"
```

This creates a compressed file archive containing all the new changes.

Now I simply need to diff this bundle with my local, however am having difficulty optimizing this. Currently, I am using variations on the following command:

```
hg -R "C:\Sandboxes\Temp\temp.hg" bcomp -r default
```

Alas, I am still having difficulty perfecting this...any insight is appreciated.

Comment: In order to help everyone else focus on your issue.  There isn't a need to indicate an "update" happened, we can see that, because it tells us when the question was last revised.  If you are changing the question, remove as much noise as possible, if your question is now about a mercurial command, just include the information to explain your goals and state the question itself.  **If you remove the noise I promise you, the result, will be an answer you can use.**

Comment: seems pretty clear to me...just put a post-it note over the 'update' string